# Assign JSON data from file to variable class provider

Tags: flutter

I tried to assign a value from JSON data in a file to the variable in the class provider. But file reading is async function. I tried to assign value by use `.then` but it doesn't work.

```
class CounterModel extends ChangeNotifier{
   static CounterStorage storage = CounterStorage();
   static String jsonData = await storage.readCounter();
   static List<dynamic> data = jsonDecode();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to call it inside a function like this

```
static String jsonData = "";

getJsonData() async {

  jsonData = await storage.readCounter();

}
```

Comment: Not working, it said
```The following FormatException was thrown building Consumer<CounterModel>(dirty, dependencies: [_InheritedProviderScope<CounterModel>]):
Unexpected end of input (at character 1)

^
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this

```
class CounterModel extends ChangeNotifier{
   static CounterStorage storage = CounterStorage();
   static String jsonData = getStorage(storage);
   static List<dynamic> data = jsonDecode();

}

getStorage(CounterStorage storage)async{
    String jsondata = await storage.readCounter();
    return jsondata.toString();
}
```

Comment: ```type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'```
Try to cast to string but still doesn't work

Comment: you just add string before `getStorage `

Comment: ```Functions marked 'async' must have a return type assignable to 'Future'.
Try fixing the return type of the function, or removing the modifier 'async' from the function body.dart(illegal_async_return_type)```

Comment: i updated my answer with `return jsondata.toString()`

Comment: add this `Future<String> getStorage(CounterStorage storage)async{
    String jsondata = await storage.readCounter();
    return jsondata.toString();
} `

Comment: That's the same as my code `storage.readCounter()` return `Future<String>` too. And it needs `await` to call